# Macbook Pro - VirtualBox 5 - Ubuntu server 14.4 static IP

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, macbook-pro, osx-el-capitan

I'm using VirtualBox and I have the Ubuntu Server 14.4 installed, I changed from dhcp to static ip, my network interface file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 10.5.60.7
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     network 10.5.60.0
     broadcast 10.5.60.255
     gateway 10.5.60.1
     dns-nameservers 10.5.60.2
```

But when I try updates my server, I'm getting the follow error:

Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'.

Comment: Can you ping your gateway and DNS server?  How about an external IP like `google.com`?

Comment: No, I tried now, and is not working. 'unknown host google.com'

Comment: How about the gateway and DNS IPs?

Comment: ping gateway and dns 'Destination Host Unreachable'.

Comment: @heavyd, I have made downgrade to 4.3 version and ping is working.